Managing API changes across iOS and Android apps with different approval timelines to avoid compatibility issues
How to manage different versions of an iOS and Android app given varying approval times without causing compatibility issues?
I'm dealing with a challenge where the iOS and Android app approval processes take different amounts of time, leading to potential compatibility issues between the backend and frontend during updates.
Scenario:
Suppose I have a login API that currently returns a token field, and I need to rename it to tokenJWT. The app's frontend must be updated accordingly. However, if the new backend version with tokenJWT goes live before the app updates are approved in both stores, users might experience issues since the app still expects token.
Question:
How can I effectively manage these discrepancies to ensure that my backend and frontend remain compatible? Are there best practices for handling different versions across iOS and Android, especially when critical API changes are involved?
I attempted to coordinate backend updates with app releases, either by delaying the backend changes until both iOS and Android updates were approved or by maintaining backward compatibility in the API.
What I was expecting:
I expected that either approach would prevent issues, but managing these versions manually is complex and prone to errors, especially when dealing with critical changes that need to be deployed simultaneously across platforms.

"However, if the new backend version with tokenJWT goes live before the app updates are approved in both stores, users might experience issues since the app still expects token" -- you need to support both names for backwards compatibility, until such time as you deem that the need for the old name has declined enough to drop support for it. A side effect of backwards compatibility is that it handles the scenario in your question.

So lets say you change the parameters for the backend from v1 to v2. The order of operations should be:
1)Roll out v2 while still keeping v1.  either the endpoint needs to be smart enough to handle either set of parameters, or you make v2 a new endpoint entirely.
2)Put out versions of all client apps to use v2 after 1 is rolled out to prod.
3)Wait for both to be in production
4)Either monitor drop off of old versions until the use of clients knowing only v1 is low enough to be acceptable breakage or use a force upgrade mechanism (such as having the client check the version it needs to be at startup and not allowing the app to be used until they upgrade).  If possible I would still gate v1/v2 usage here on a feature flag, so if you find a bug you can roll back without a new client version.
5)Once you're satisfied with stability and either force a client upgrade or are willing to break the remaining laggers, you can remove the v1 endpoints.  This gap will typically be a few months, but I do know companies that do years.
This is the general pattern.  It can change a bit based on type of app-  how mission critical is it to prevent downtime, how reliably can you trust users to upgrade, etc.
